# How to search an element by its name in a web page using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am creating groups randomly. Then i need to check whether that group has been created or not. is there any way to search the group by its given name.
or element in a webpage by its name. i am trying it by using By.name locator, but not able to do that.

I just want to get an element in webpage by its name which is given by me/user.
For Ex: i have created a group "gr907", So how i can search or verify whether group having name "gr907" has been created or not.

Kindly Suggest

Comment: post the html code

Comment: Threre is no html code as group is creatig at runtime... so how would i know that what will be the html code for would be creating group name. Only group name i can store in a string

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2485/webdriver-find-elements-by-text/2486

Comment: Can you create the 'group' in your scenario, and post the HTML that shows said 'group'?

Comment: yes i am creating groups with random names <span class="grpName">Gr9006</span>

Comment: So even group names are generating at run time and that i can store in a string variable... But after taht not able to search with that name

Comment: Like this i am generating random group names String randomNumbers =RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(4);
   String GroupName = "Gr" +randomNumbers;
  return GroupName;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example element you gave in the comment for your initial post - `<span class="grpName">Gr9006</span>` - and assuming that other relevant elements share the same class attribute, you could use the following example to retrieve a list of suitable WebElements:

`List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("grpName"));`

If this doesn't work, then your next course of action could be to make an XPath expression that identifies `span` tags whose inner text starts with "Gr", such as:

`List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'gr')]"));`

To find a single element containing the group name created at run time as its exact text content, you can simply pass it in to an XPath like so;

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='" + group name + "']");`

Comment: Yes, this will work but there will so many groups starting from "gr" how recently created group will be identified as i am creating its with random names at run time. how will it verify that yes the group which i created now or supposing my next action is to send message in that group only how will i know what the group name is.... Kindly look into this

Comment: Thank You Tom Trumper it worked... Thanks a lot for the the help

Comment: You're welcome, please can you tag my answer as accepted?

Comment: I believe there should be a green outlined checkmark to the left of my answer you can click to mark it as accepted?